# Film con sottotitoli italiani che corrispondono al parlato?

Tags: resources

Sto cercando, per una persona che sta imparando l'italiano, film con sottotitoli che corrispondano al parlato italiano, cioè le parole che leggo sullo schermo sono le stesse che gli attori/doppiatori pronunciano nella versione italiana.

Purtroppo in molti casi i sottotitoli contengono una traduzione diversa, e nella mia esperienza quelli che corrispondono sono una minoranza.

Per esempio su Netflix Harry Potter e la serie Bridgerton hanno sottotitoli fedeli al parlato, mentre molti altri film no.

Sapreste indicarmi o un modo per cercare sottitoli con questa caratteristica (sia su piattaforme streaming come Netflix, sia su siti di sottotitoli da appaiare a film scaricati da internet)? O almeno qualcuno sa indicarmi alcuni film/serie che ce l'hanno?

Comment: Capisco bene questa esigenza (la sento anch'io per altre lingue), ma il fatto è che il doppiaggio e i sottotitoli sono creati da équipe diverse, con vincoli diversi, e quindi, paradossalmente, proprio se sono fatti professionalmente tendono a differire. L'adattamento per il doppiaggio deve tenere conto dei tempi e dei movimenti delle labbra, mentre ogni sottotitolo ha una lunghezza massima, una durata minima per cui deve apparire e altri requisiti.

Comment: Per curiosità, come mai questa persona non vede film e serie italiani? Forse sarebbe meglio, sia per l'italiano che imparerebbe (rispetto al “doppiaggese”) sia perché i sottotitoli – non essendo una traduzione ma una semplice trascrizione – sarebbero più vicini ai dialoghi (anche se forse un po' scorciati).

Comment: @DaG Film e serie italiani non hanno sottotitoli italiani migliori. Anzi, a volte non ce li hanno proprio (ad esempio, *Boris*).

Comment: @DaG Sull'utilità di guardare film e serie italiane rispetto a materiale doppiato, credo che dipenda molto dal livello. Il "doppiaggese" è più semplice come lingua, e i film italiani hanno molti accenti locali (in quasi tutte le commedie italiane c'è un personaggio che parla con un forte accento regionale) e riferimenti culturali difficili da comprendere. Sono argomenti utili da imparare a livello più avanzato, ma per un principiante suggerirei di partire dal 'doppiaggese' per non scoraggiarsi. In ogni caso nelle risposte indicate pure sia film italiani che doppiati.

Comment: Luna Nera su Netflix

Comment: Grazie @HeitorChang ! Anche se è una serie sola postala pure come risposta e avrai il mio voto positivo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ho trovato la serie Luna Nera su Netflix, peccato che ci sono appena 6 episodi.

P.S. Ho cercato "audio in italian" per trovare questa serie.